# Integration testing with Embedded Postgres

Tags: java, postgresql, spring-boot, gitlab-ci

I followed the instructions mentioned here: https://medium.com/@valeryyakovlev/embedded-postgres-test-config-ab8e4e0d3256

It works fine when I run locally but gives the following error when built on gitlab CI.

```
            Caused by:
            org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [ru.yandex.qatools.embed.postgresql.EmbeddedPostgres]: Factory method 'embeddedPostgres' threw exception; nested exception is de.flapdoodle.embed.process.exceptions.DistributionException: java.io.IOException: Could not open inputStream for http://get.enterprisedb.com/postgresql/postgresql-11.1-1-linux-x64-binaries.tar.gz

                Caused by:
                de.flapdoodle.embed.process.exceptions.DistributionException: java.io.IOException: Could not open inputStream for http://get.enterprisedb.com/postgresql/postgresql-11.1-1-linux-x64-binaries.tar.gz

                    Caused by:
                    java.io.IOException: Could not open inputStream for http://get.enterprisedb.com/postgresql/postgresql-11.1-1-linux-x64-binaries.tar.gz

                        Caused by:
                        java.io.IOException: Server returned HTTP response code: 403 for URL: http://get.enterprisedb.com/postgresql/postgresql-11.1-1-linux-x64-binaries.tar.gz

Gradle Test Executor 1 finished executing tests.
```

I found some sources mentioning to customize proxy: https://github.com/flapdoodle-oss/de.flapdoodle.embed.mongo#customize-proxy-for-download

It didn't help.